# Magento System Config: What's the use of frontend_type for section and groups?

Tags: php, magento, configuration

In the `system.xml` I can define a `frontend_type` for a section and for groups.

Example for `Mage_Catalog`.

```
<sections>
    <catalog translate="label" module="catalog">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Catalog</label>
        <tab>catalog</tab>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>40</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
            <frontend translate="label">
                <label>Frontend</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
```

Is there any example where this is *not* text? What would be a use-case?

Comment: Good question. It looks like they are really ignored during rendering.

Comment: Did you look up the code where it is ignored? Feel free to post it as a real answer.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand from [this article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_configuration_in_depth_tutorial) by Alan Storm, the value of `<frontend_type/>` is used in a Factory style pattern to instantiate a class with a format of

```
Varien_Data_Form_Element_Type
```

where `Type` is the value of the `<frontend_type/>`. This happens in the `addField` method of the `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract` class which is not called on sections and groups.